# How to load STL file in Helixtoolkit.SharpDX?

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using Helixtoolkit in my c# WPF project. 
And It seems my model is so huge that the performance is very bad.(I loaded a human skull model).
Here is the way I load the model

```
ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();
_modleGroup = import.Load(modelpath);
```

I want to use Helixtoolkit.SharpDX to show the model in `Viewport3DX`,  I think it will be better on performance.

The sample code only can load.obj and .3ds file. I tried to load the stl file but got error(return garbled message).It seems Helixtoolkit.SharpDX doesn't provide the STLReader like:

```
var reader = new StudioReader();
var reader = new ObjReader();
```

Hope anyone could teach me to load stl file in  `Viewport3DX`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://interplayoflight.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/sharpdx-and-3d-model-loading/). The article provides a quite decent example how it can be done using the popular [Assimp](http://www.assimp.org) library.

Also, the comments there suggest that SharpDX supports interoperation with Assimp directly.